# Create proportion with group by on pandas dataFrame by two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have this dataset:

```
df = d = pd.DataFrame({
'duplicates': [
     [('007', "us1", "us2", "time1", 'time2', 4)],
     [('008', "us1", "us2", "time1", 'time2', 5)],
     [('009', "us1", "us2", "time1", 'time2', 6)],
     [('007', 'us2', "us3", "time1", 'time2', 4)],
     [('008', 'us2', "us3", "time1", 'time2', 7)], 
     [('009', 'us2', "us3", "time1", 'time2', 11)], 
     [('001', 'us5', 'us1', "time1", 'time2', 0)], 
     [('008', 'us5', 'us1', "time1", 'time2', 19)], 
     [('007',"us3", "us2", "time1", 'time2', 2)],
     [('007',"us3", "us2", "time1", 'time2', 34)],
     [('009',"us3", "us2", "time1", 'time2', 67)]],
'numberOfInteractions': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 1, 11]
   })
```

That I manipule like this:

```
df['duplicates'] = df.apply(
            lambda x: [(x['numberOfInteractions'],a, b, c, d, e, f) for a, b, c, d, e, f in x.duplicates], 1)


user_record_access =(pd.DataFrame(df["duplicates"].explode().tolist(),
                  columns=["numberOfInteractions", "ID","USER1","USER2","TAU1","TAU2","DELAY"])
     .groupby(["USER1","USER2"])["numberOfInteractions"]
     .agg(sum).to_frame().reset_index())
```

Then I want to arrive at a dataset like this:

```
USER1   USER2   numberOfInteractions    proportion
us1     us2       6                     0.315789
us2     us3       15                    1
us3     us2       13                    0.684211
us5     us1       15                    1.000000
```

The 'proportion' in this case I want:

```
- numberOfInteractions of the line/sum(numberOfInteractions of USER2)
```

For example:

- Giving the first line I get us1 us2 and then I do 6/(13+6) . (Being 13 and 6 all the numberOfInteractions of us2 as USER2)

But I cannot find out how, I tried some things (like this one below) but without success:

```
user_record_access['proportion'] = user_record_access['numberOfInteractions']/user_record_access['sumUSER2'] #.apply(lambda x: x['numberOfInteractions']/x['numberOfInteractions'].sum(skipna=True)).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use:**

```
# Note: Here 'df1' refers to the dataframe 'user_record_access'
s = df1.groupby('USER2')['numberOfInteractions'].transform('sum')
df1['proportion'] = df1['numberOfInteractions'].div(s)
```

---

**Details:**

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on column `USER2` and use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html)  to transfrom the column `numberOfInteractions` using [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
print(s)
0    19
1    15
2    19
3    15
Name: USER2, dtype: int64
```

Use [`Series.div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html) and divide the column `numberOfInteractions` by the transformed series `s` and assign this result back to new column `proportions`.

```
print(df1)
  USER1 USER2  numberOfInteractions  proportion
0   us1   us2                     6    0.315789
1   us2   us3                    15    1.000000
2   us3   us2                    13    0.684211
3   us5   us1                    15    1.000000
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you a lot! I tried an idea like yours before, but I didn't get good results, here: df1.groupby('USER2')['numberOfInteractions'].agg(sum).reset_index()['numberOfInteractions'] . Can you explain me why this do not work? I've seen you use a map, and this makes it works but I cannot see why :)

Comment: Sure.. you code is almost good but as you are aggregating the dataframe each aggregated `sum` value corresponds to one user, so here the number of rows are less in aggregated column that in the original dataframe that's why  its not working. One other idea is we can use `transform` instead of `map`. Further to divide the `numberOfInteraction` with aggregated column we require indices to match in both the series.

Comment: ahhhhh, perfect, that makes total sense! Thank you! Also, I will try with transform to practice ;)

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira Edited the solution to use `groupby.transform` instead, as it is more concise and obvious solution here.